# Should the FrameLayout be the container for different Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, containers

I have a general question about the design of Fragments in Android. I have a BottomNavigationBar in my app and I intend to use the Jetpack Navigation Components (which I have not done yet). I would like to have a single Activity and multiple Fragments (as this is what everyone tells me to use). Now the different Fragments should be displayed in a Container, right? Can I use a FrameLayout for that and put all the fragments inside it? Of course the Fragments should not be displayed at the same time but depending on which Fragment is choosen. I have created an example XML-layout file for the Activity that should serve as the container and I inserted two Fragments in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />




    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/info_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Info_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/info_fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Info_Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        ></fragment>
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is this the correct approach? Or how else can a single Activity serve multiple Fragments? I have to somehow link them to the activity, right?

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: Yes. I do the same, using single Activity and multiple fragment in app, and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Sanwal for your comment. So you also use the FrameLayout and put fragments inside them in the XML layout file?

Comment: I am using FrameLayout

Comment: Thanks Sanwal for your comment. What about the Jetpack Navigation Components? Can you use them together with this approach or is it just another approach for hosting and navigation multiple fragments?

Comment: I am not using Jetpack Navigation Components in current app with is scenario, So I am not able to help you/